# Comparing RGB colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, colors, rgb

I'm trying to compare two RGB colors in a guessing game. There are 6 squares with 6 different colors. When the user clicks on the color that matches `pickedColor`, the result should be 'Correct!'. But I never get that result.

This is my code:

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,255)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(255,0,255)"
];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    //add initinal colors to squares
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

    //add the click listener to the squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var clickedColor = this.style.background;

        if (clickedColor === pickedColor) alert("Correct!");
        else alert("Incorrect!");
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it always alerts the second option"

Comment: And did you log the returned color to the console? Most browsers use RGBA these days, and there's no guarantee that the browser will return a string looking like the ones you have, old browsers could return hex, new browsers could return HSL, who knows

Comment: @Pabs123 I think that he means that clickedColor === pickedColor always returns false (else is the 2nd statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I set up an example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMRmZr) and it looks like the problem is that your initial set of colours don't have spaces between the commas:

```
var colors = [
  "rgb(255,0,0)",
  "rgb(255,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,255)",
  "rgb(0,0,255)",
  "rgb(255,0,255)"
];
```

clickedColor has no spaces and the pickedColor does, so changing this to:

```
var colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
];
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: @LuisMartinez - actually, you shouldn't be doing this at all, comparing colors returned by the browser is always a bad idea, as you have no control over what the browser will return.

Comment: Try to use tools like debuggers or console logs to track your errors! it's ok to make little mistakes, so long as you can track them down somehow

Comment: i was learning how to working with the DOM with this Little game. But thanks for the advice adeneo

Comment: I try to see what i was getting on the inspect element but that didn't see it haha thanks again pabs

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that the color expression `'rgb(0,255,255)'` is formatted differently by the browser. In the test `clickedColor === pickedColor`, you're comparing two strings that no longer look the same even if they represent the same color.

Different browsers can represent an RGB color in different ways, so it's unsafe to pick a particular format. A better approach is to extract the color components from the strings and compare the component values one by one, as in the code below.

```
function rgbExtract(s) {
  var match = /^\s*rgb\(\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)\s*$/.exec(s);
  if (match === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return { r: parseInt(match[1], 10),
           g: parseInt(match[2], 10),
           b: parseInt(match[3], 10) };
}

function rgbMatches(sText, tText) {
  var sColor = rgbExtract(sText),
      tColor = rgbExtract(tText);
  if (sColor === null || tColor === null) {
    return false;
  }
  var componentNames = [ 'r', 'g', 'b' ];
  for (var i = 0; i < componentNames.length; ++i) {
    var name = componentNames[i];
    if (sColor[name] != tColor[name]) {
      return false;
    }
  } 
  return true;
}
```

The `rgbMatches` function is demonstrated in the following snippet. You'll see that you can now click on the square with the correct color and you'll get the appropriate message even though the underlying RGB strings are formatted differently.

```js
var colors = [
  "rgb(255,0,0)",
  "rgb(255,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,255)",
  "rgb(0,0,255)",
  "rgb(255,0,255)"
];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

function message(s) {
  document.getElementById('messageContainer').innerHTML = s;
}

function rgbExtract(s) {
  var match = /^\s*rgb\(\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)\s*$/.exec(s);
  if (match === null) {
    return null;
  }
  return { r: parseInt(match[1], 10),
           g: parseInt(match[2], 10),
           b: parseInt(match[3], 10) };
}

function rgbMatches(sText, tText) {
  var sColor = rgbExtract(sText),
      tColor = rgbExtract(tText);
  if (sColor === null || tColor === null) {
    return false;
  }
  var componentNames = [ 'r', 'g', 'b' ];
  for (var i = 0; i < componentNames.length; ++i) {
    var name = componentNames[i];
    if (sColor[name] != tColor[name]) {
      return false;
    }
  } 
  return true;
}

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i) {
  var square = squares[i];
  square.style.background = colors[i];
  square.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;
    if (rgbMatches(clickedColor, pickedColor)) {
        message('Correct! ' + clickedColor + ' matches ' + pickedColor);
    } else {
        message('Incorrect. ' + clickedColor + ' doesn\'t match ' + pickedColor);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.output {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>

<div class="output" id="colorDisplay"></div>

<div class="output" id="messageContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Let's hope the browser won't return the color in hex format.

Comment: This is more complicated but truly effectively. thanks so much i take that into account

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of comparing two rgb strings like this. Different browsers may store style background colors differently (as you have already discovered).

I would suggest writing a custom comparison function which parses two rgb strings and compares them.

Or you could convert them to hex color values and compare those instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust the color returned by the browser. Different browsers will use different formats.

Instead, use classes or `data-*` attributes to set the color, and check that:

```js
var colors = ["red", "yellow", "lime", "cyan", "blue", "fuchsia"],
    squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square"),
    pickedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)],
    message = document.getElementById("messageContainer");
document.getElementById("colorDisplay").textContent = pickedColor;
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; ++i) {
  squares[i].setAttribute('data-color', colors[i]);
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var clickedColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
    message.textContent = clickedColor === pickedColor
      ? "Correct!" : "Incorrect!";
  });
}
```

```css
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.output {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
[data-color=red] { background: rgb(255,0,0) }
[data-color=yellow] { background: rgb(255,255,0) }
[data-color=lime] { background: rgb(0,255,0) }
[data-color=cyan] { background: rgb(0,255,255) }
[data-color=blue] { background: rgb(0,0,255) }
[data-color=fuchsia] { background: rgb(255,0,255) }
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="output" id="colorDisplay"></div>
<div class="output" id="messageContainer"></div>
```